# How to force the Paint method of Richtextbox not to erase background color

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, richtextbox

i want to ask how can i force that a richtextbox control does not erase its background when it paints.

i tried to handle the WM_ERASEBKGND message but it did not work.

Thanks !

Comment: Derive your own class from RTB and override WndProc to catch message 0x14.  Not painting the background is only interesting for random pixel generation.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows a transparent RichTextBox:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13197/Alpha-Blended-Transparent-Capable-TextBox-and-Rich

Comment: Thanks but it has no scrollbars.

Comment: You have to set the `Scrollbars` property on `Both`